# Ruby on Rails Data Modeling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a User table with the following schema:

`User -- id , name , age etc`

and a Ride table with the following schema:

`Ride -- id , from , to etc.`

I also have a Bookings table with the schema:
`Booking - id, User_id, Ride_id`

Is there any way I can describe the details about the ride like `from , to etc` and also details about the user who made the booking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have the following relationship:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :rides, :through => :bookings
end

class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :ride
end

class Ride < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :users, :through => :bookings
end
```

You can retrieve any information you want.

```
booking = Booking.find(1)
booking.user.name
=> #return user name
booking.ride.from
=> #return ride from
etc
```

Furthermore, the `:through` allows you to access the `user` directly from `ride` and vice-versa:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.rides
=> #return all rides for that user
```

Answer (score 0):

Create models User, Ride and Booking. Then you can use `booking.ride.from`, `user.bookings.last.ride.to`. This all is explained here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html.